# Using bigger circle background color in columns

Tags: html, css

I have to make some text in a webpage inside a circle, I know this can be done trough CSS and this is my code

```
.circle-div{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: rgba(75,113,252, 0.85);
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: white;
 padding:15%;
}
```

But the problem is, when I try to make the circle bigger, the other columns near it lose their alignment (e.g. I set a width and height of 460px) here's an example of it should be:

Circle div | Text column | Text Column

Is there any possible way to increase the background-size without altering/crossing with the other columns?

Comment: please share your html snippet as well

Comment: Did my answer help you? ... If not, what else can I do to make it work how you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10%;
}
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(75,113,252, 0.85);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Circle</div><div>Col2</div><div>Col2</div>
```